# Assembly - jump instruction in machine code

Tags: assembly, x86

[image: ji]

Why the jump instruction in line 1B (for example) become EBBD?

I know that "jmp" = EB
But how BD is calculated?

Comment: Please avoid pictures of code.  Refer to the instruction set reference for details on the instruction encoding.  In this case, it's a signed 8 bit offset from the address of the instruction following the jump instruction.

Comment: Why in the line of thr label L2 is offset of FE. Shouldnt is be FD?

Comment: Recall that `FE` represents the signed offset `-2` which is correct.  Why do you expect `FD` (signed offset `-3`)?

Comment: @fuz, you're correct in all but one aspect - the offset to `L` from the `JMP` at `1B`, would be `ED` rather than `BD`.

Comment: @paxdiablo That could have just been a printing or scanning error.  One of the reasons why I dislike when people post pictures of code.

Comment: @fuz, I suspect you're right about the printing error (as per my answer). But it's likely that OP only *had* the image, since it looks like it came from a book, and wanted to know why the `BD` offset was doing what it was doing (or not, as the case may be). Requesting textual code would add little there other than forcing OP to type it in, possibly resulting in *more* errors :-) I'm all for requiring text code where possible (I've often complained to questioners myself when they do this) - I just suspect it *wasn't* possible/advisable in this *particular* case.

Answer (score 6):

A short jump uses a signed offset added to the address of the instruction following the `JMP`.

For example, the first `JMP L2` has an offset of `FE` which equates to `-2`, and adding that to the address of the instruction following that `JMP` gives you the address of that `JMP`.

However, that's *not* the case for the first `JMP L` since the offset needed there would be `E8` (the second `JMP L` is also incorrect, it should have the offset `E6`). You can confirm this if you hop on to an online x86 assembler site such as [this one](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) and enter:

```
    mov ecx,2
l:  mov edx,0
    inc edx
    sub ecx,1
    nop
    nop
    nop
    setz al
    shl al,1
    mov byte [l1+1],al
l1: jmp l
    jmp l
    mov byte [l2+1],al
l2: jmp l
    jmp l2
    mov eax,edx
    ret
```

You'll notice those extra three `NOP` lines, they're because the assembler chooses a shorter variant of `SUB ECX,1` and I just want to keep the addresses lined up with what you have. The assembled code out of that is as follows:

```
0:  b9 02 00 00 00          mov    ecx,0x2
00000005 <l>:
5:  ba 00 00 00 00          mov    edx,0x0
a:  42                      inc    edx
b:  83 e9 01                sub    ecx,0x1
e:  90                      nop
f:  90                      nop
10: 90                      nop
11: 0f 94 c0                sete   al
14: d0 e0                   shl    al,1
16: a2 1c 00 00 00          mov    ds:0x1c,al
0000001b <l1>:
1b: eb e8                   jmp    5 <l>
1d: eb e6                   jmp    5 <l>
1f: a2 25 00 00 00          mov    ds:0x25,al
00000024 <l2>:
24: eb fe                   jmp    24 <l2>
26: eb fc                   jmp    24 <l2>
28: 89 d0                   mov    eax,edx
2a: c3                      ret
```

It's evident from that that the encoding of the first *two* jumps is incorrect in your posted code. They should be `EbE8/EbE6` rather than `EBBD/EBEB`. In fact, the latter pair wouldn't even make sense if they were going to some *other* label, since the difference between them should be exactly two if they're jumping to the *same* label.

---

One thing to be wary of however: if you examine the code closely, you'll see that it's actually self modifying, as the `JMP` instructions are modified with statements like:

```
MOV BYTE [L1 + 1],  AL
```

(changing the offset of the instruction at `L1`). Self-modifying code can be used for the purposes of obfuscation, or making it difficult to reverse-engineer software, and it *may* be that the code has already undergone the changes that will be applied.

It would be useful to watch that code dynamically as the self-changes are *made,* to see how they affect the code, but the rough outcome of my *static* analysis follows:

```
Address  Effect
-------  ------
  00     ecx = 2
  05     edx = 0
  0a     edx = 1
  0b     ecx = 1, zflag=F
  11     al = 0 (because zflag=F)
  14     al stays 0
  16     instruction at 1b becomes eb00, jmp 1d
  1b     jumps to 1d
  1d     jumps to 0a
  0a     edx = 2
  0b     ecx = 0, zflag=T
  11     al = 1 (because zflag=T)
  14     al = 2
  16     instruction at 1b becomes eb02, jmp 1f
  1b     jumps to 1f
  1f     instruction at 24 becomes eb02, jmp 28
  24     jumps to 28
  28     eax = 2
  2a     returns
```

Based on that, the instruction at `L1` should never become `EBBD` (it's only ever changed to `EB00` or `EB02`) so it's far more likely that what you have there is a simple misprint of the text (especially given the error in the second `JMP L` which is *never* modified). I'd guess authors are no more perfect than the rest of us :-)