# How to use INT 3 to execute code backward in DOS

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I read from a blog post saying that back in the DOS days (not sure if it's possible under NT), there was a technique to execute code in backwards. It then went on to say that the idea was to execute say operation N, then use INT 3 to modify the instruction pointer to go backwards.

I'm trying to find more information regarding this but Googling so far didn't bring up anything close, and a lot of assembly code seems to target 32-bit and 64-bit architectures so I'm not sure if that's useful. I did find what INT 3 does:

> Debuggers use this interrupt to establish breakpoints in a program
> that is being debugged.  This is normally done by substituting an INT
> 3 instruction, which is one byte long, for a byte in the actual
> program.  The original byte from the program is restored by the
> debugger after it receives control through INT 3.

So my guess is, this "original byte" could be a JUMP instruction, and the second byte is the offset of the instruction ([another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597760/assembly-jump-instruction-in-machine-code)). The program maybe somehow modify the "stored" original byte and replaced it with a different offset. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Please provide the blog post that claimed this. Otherwise we have to guess at what the author was trying to say.

Comment: You can't *execute code backward*. You can change the instruction pointer to re-execute code that has been run before, but the code still executes forward. It's only useful (very rarely) when debugging.

Comment: x86 machine code can't be unambiguously decoded backwards.  There's no reliable way hardware *could* have such a feature.  (Other ISAs with fixed-width instructions don't either, though; it's not worth baking extra complexity into the ISA just for very rarely useful debugger tricks.)  If you're talking about rewinding to previous machine states, that's something GDB `record` can do, letting you "undo" instructions, i.e. single-step backwards. But that's not executing in reverse order, that's reloading saved states from memory to also restore register values (since some ops like OR are one-way)

Comment: @RaymondChen it's actually a Zhihu post (in Chinese), then the author gave me a link to another piece of code that "executes" backwards: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/587279257

Comment: The blog post is executing instructions in reverse order: Spatial reversal, not temporal reversal. The blog post quotes somebody else talking about int3, but the blog post itself uses the trace flag to execute single instructions. After each instruction executes, it updates the program counter to point to the instruction prior to the one that just executed. (Located with the help of a separate preprocessing pass that identifies the start of each instruction, based on an assembly file.) This is a parlor trick, and doesn't match what people usually mean by "executing backward".

Comment: Thanks! I'm not proficient with assembly language but indeed it doesn't use INT 3. I'll see if I can find more information on retro virus research sites.